# making 2 specific buttons fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am wrinting a script in jQuery for the friend requests page for my software.
this is what i'm currently rockin'

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.acceptfriend').click(function(){
var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            url : 'inc/ajax.php',
            type : 'POST',
            data : {
                action : 'accept_friend',
                uid : $(this).data('uid')
            },
            dataType : 'JSON',
            success : function(result) {
                if (result.xhr == 'success') {
                    $( self ).fadeOut( 1000 );
                } else if (result.xhr == 'error'){
                    alert('An internal error accoured, try again later.');
            }
  }
    });
});
})
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.rejectfriend').click(function(){
var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            url : 'inc/ajax.php',
            type : 'POST',
            data : {
                action : 'reject_friend',
                uid : $(this).data('uid')
            },
            dataType : 'JSON',
            success : function(result) {
                if (result.xhr == 'success') {
                    $( self ).fadeOut( 1000 );
                } else if (result.xhr == 'error'){
                    alert('An internal error accoured, try again later.');
            }
  }
    });
});
})
```

but the problem is i want to make both accept and ignore buttons to fade out if one of them is clicked, i can't use their class names because if i do then ALL buttons with that class on that page are faded out.
PS. 
i know that code is very messy but that's just for now, i will clean it later.
**EDIT**
Here's the HTML makup i use for the jQuery above:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">
<a href="profile.php?id=12" class="tip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-animation="true" data-original-title="anerikanarmyant"><img style="padding-bottom: 5px;" src="http://minecraft-websites.com/assets/images/default_profile_pic.jpg"width="48" height="48"></a>   anerikanarmyant
<div class="pull-right">
<div class="btn-group">
<button data-uid="12" type="button" class="btn btn-success acceptfriend">Accept</button>
<button data-uid="12" type="button" class="btn btn-danger rejectfriend">Ignore</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and this code is repeated for every friend request recived.

Comment: You're going to have post some HTML, showing us how the buttons are placed in the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the 2 appraches :

**1.** http://jsfiddle.net/xWE3V/

```
$('.acceptfriend,.rejectfriend').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500);
});
```

**2.** http://jsfiddle.net/P6U76/

```
$('.acceptfriend').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings( ".rejectfriend" ).fadeOut(500);
    $(this).fadeOut(500);
});

$('.rejectfriend').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings( ".acceptfriend" ).fadeOut(500);
    $(this).fadeOut(500);
});
```

Comment: i tried method 2 and got this error in JS console : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'opacity' in undefined "

Comment: i had to use the self variable i declered in the original code but other then the second method worked perfectly, thanks!